# How to insert custom query in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to insert custom data using grails I'm trying this

`University.executeQuery("INSERT INTO University (universityName, address, universityId, password) values(?,?,?,?)", [r.universityName],[r.country],[username],[password])`

I believe that I'm doing wrong; whats the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it's an update not a query, so if anything you would use `executeUpdate`. But if you're just inserting a row into a table that corresponds to a domain class use `save()`:

```
new University(universityName: r.universityName,
               address: r.country,
               universityId: username,
               password: password).save()
```

Comment: getting this error while using above University.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []